# Redirecting root of site to subdirectory using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

A site of mine has all the files stored in a subdirectory. Previously, I used a 301 redirect to send visitors from `site.com/specific/page` to `site.com/subdirectory/specific/page`.

I am now using this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.php [L]
```

This means the URL is cleaner. However, **is there a way to make the htaccess redirect people using the subdirectory to the cleaner URL?** i.e. if someone goes to `site.com/subdirectory/specific/page`, is there a way to make the URL `site.com/specific/page`, while showing the content from `site.com/subdirectory/specific/page`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, buit instead of rewriting, youn would redirect..

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/subdirectory/(.*)" "/$1"
```

That way, if they hit any subdirectory directly, they will be redirected to the cleaner URL, where your rules above will kick in.