# .htaccess How to redirect root URL to subdirectory files, rewrite to clean URL AND not affect subdomains?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

*Haven't been able to find what I'm looking for in .htaccess QA's on here so forgive me if this is duplicate.* I have the following problem with a static HTML site. Structure is below.

My relative paths in `info.html` and `contact.html` have to use `/home/css/style.css` while `index.html` uses `/css/style.css`. Thanks for help.

```
Root
- .htaccess
↳ Drupal
  - .git
↳ Dev
  - .git
↳ Home
  - .htaccess
  - .git
  - css
  - js
  - img
  - info.html
  - contact.html
  - index.html
```

**Goal**

- `Dev.example.com` to use all the files from `/Dev`
- `example.com` to use all the files from `example.com/home`
- `example.com/info` to redirect from `example.com/home/info.html`.
- `example.com/contact` to redirect from `example.com/home/contact.html`.

**What I've tried so far**

in root .htaccess

```
      # Set a default home directory, (this subfolder always loads)
  # RewriteEngine On
  # RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /home/
  # # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
  # RewriteRule ^home/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]

  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
  # RewriteRule !^home/ home%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

  Options -Indexes

  ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html

  # compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

  <FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js)$">
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
  </FilesMatch>

  RedirectMatch 404 "(?:.*)/(?:\.git|file_or_dir)(?:/.*)?$"

  # remove .html from html file names
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
  RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]
```

And in Root/drupal .htaccess

```
default drupal stuff
```

**Closest answers I could find on SO:**

- [.htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)
- [Changing all my website links: what is the best way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073832/changing-all-my-website-links-the-best-way?lq=1)
- [Redirecting root of site to subdirectory using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898946/redirecting-root-of-site-to-subdirectory-using-htaccess)
- [htaccess subdirectory URLS to root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209795/htaccess-subdirectory-urls-to-root)

---

**EDIT:** I ended up following, partially, the advice given because I have separate git repos per subdirectory. Thanks @Jon Lin and @tttony!

**New problem:** My .htaccess in root doesn't let me view my drupal installation in subfolder.

- `Drupal.examples.com` uses all the drupal files from `/Drupal`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do, by far, is just make `home` your document root and not have to worry about having a subdirectory.

But for what you have to work, the first thing you need to do is route *everything* to `/home` and not just the `/` request:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/$1 [L]
```

Secondly, this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
```

will always fail if you have a trailing slash, since it'll try to check for files that look like this:

```
/home/contact/.html
```

Try this instead:

```
# remove .html from html file names
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/home/%1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Added more details to my folder structure.  Will this affect your answer?

Comment: @Danger14 don't think so

Comment: I can't access any subdomains (Staging.example.com maps to Root/Staging) now. How do I edit my .htaccess in root to allow access to subdomains?

Comment: @Danger14 try adding either conditions to exclude the subdomain directories (e.g. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(staging|other_subdomain|subdomain2)`) or you can add !-f and !-d checks against `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`. The conditions need to go above the `RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]` rule.

Answer (score 2):

I've had that issues with sub-folders, you can try use [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) in your root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /home/
```

But I found that it's better to use just one .htaccess file in the root folder

```
# remove .html from html file names
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond home/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ home/$1.html [L]
```